# Shibboleth Path Request Map

Tags: shibboleth

I am not sure this is even possible. It seems like this is overlapping siblings as mentioned in the documentation here:
https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SP3/pages/2065335006/HowToRequestMap
I have a web site with this structure and certain folders need to be protected and others need to be excluded. I have tried various combinations and order but cannot get them all to work.

/surveys  -excluded

v13.2.75/api -excluded

v13.2.75/CC -protected

v13.2.75/DataEntry -protected

v13.2.75/Resources -excluded

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found a solution but I cannot figure out how to post the code so it displays correctly.

Comment: Use either a four-space indent, or three backticks ``` (GitHub-style)... or highlight the code and click the "Code" button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Path name="v13.2.75" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="false">
    <Path name="CC" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
    <Path name="DataEntry" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
</Path>
```